# OPC UA standard for writing simple Java client/server

Tags: java, opc, opc-ua

I am new to OPC and is required to develop a simple OPC server using Java to test a connection with a OPC client, retrieve data through the server from a database and returning the data to the OPC client. I am having difficulties understanding the standards of OPC UA and would appreciate if anyone could highlight the standards/things to note regarding the standard in the Java OPC UA server application. For example, for a web server, HTTP header is the standard. So while receiving a HTTP request, I can decipher the HTTP header for the content and create a response header in the right format for the client browser to understand.

Comment: Creating a UA server from scratch could be complex and time consuming, have you considered using a Java UA SDK like https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/developer-kits-unified-architecture/java-stack-and-sample-applications/?

Comment: Yup, I have looked into it and look into the opcua4j on google code. Just wondering if I am retrieving the data from a database, is it preferable to load all the data from the table when the server starts, or query the table only when it is needed by the client?

Comment: It would be preferable to load the data from database each time client makes a request so as to reduce the UA server memory usage, but if you have small amount of non-changing data, then you can load them once and persist in the UA server. Generally I load the configuration data like variable name, min/max, unit etc once, but fetch the variable values each time from database.

Comment: just wondering how does the server handle dynamic data like time, temperature changes etc.. It doesn't make sense to store the data to the database every sec..

Comment: The UA server must read the dynamic values from the source which could be database, file or another system. The UA server can cache the value, but the client can force reading from source each time. If your dynamic data is coming from another system, then instead of saving these values in the database, you can read them directly from UA server.

Answer (score 0):

To be exactly, Read request has an option maxAge:

The maxAge parameter is used to direct the Server to access the value from the underlying data source, such as a device, if its copy of the data is older than that which the maxAge specifies. If the Server cannot meet the requested maximum age, it returns its “best effort” value rather than rejecting the request.
(OPC UA Spec Part 4)